# c : Reading character in scanf statement returns garbage value

Tags: c

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and gcc 4.8.4

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void main()
 {
     char c[15];
     printf("enter a character\n");
     scanf("%15c",c);
     printf("%s\n",c);
 }
```

Output:

```
enter a character
qwertyuiopasdfghjkl
qwertyuiopasdfg
```

When I execute the program above with more than 15 characters as input, the  output does not return garbage values. But when I execute the program below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char c[5];
    printf("enter a character\n");
    scanf("%5c",c);
    printf("%s\n",c);
}
```

I am giving input which is more than 5 characters. It returns output with  garbage values.

Comment: The problem is that the value read by `%15c` and `%5c` is not null-terminated, so both of your codes have undefined behaviour.

Comment: The return type of `main()` is always `int`, never `void`.  Not that this is the central problem here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Although not the central issue, C  allows `void main()` per "or in some other implementation-defined manner." C11 §5.1.2.2.1 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%c` directive is for reading individual characters and character arrays, but not for those arrays specifically used as C strings.  In particular, it does not store a null character after the last character transferred from the input.

Therefore, both of your `scanf()` calls are perfectly fine, but the subsequent `printf()` calls are not.  In each case, the contents of the array designated by `c` are not null-terminated, therefore attempting to print the array via an `%s` directive will cause `scanf()` to read past the end of the array, producing undefined behavior.  That the undefined behavior in one case seems reasonable to you and the undefined behavior in the other case does not is irrelevant.

I advise against working with unterminated string-like arrays as you are doing.  It would be better to make the arrays large enough for a terminator, and to ensure that they are, in fact, terminated.  But if you must print unterminated or possibly unterminated character arrays via `printf()`, then be sure to use the precision field of the directive to limit the number of characters that may be printed:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c[5];
    printf("enter a character\n");
    scanf("%5c", c);
    printf("%.5s\n", c);
}
```

Comment: No, @chux.  Regardless of field width, a `%c` directive tells `printf()` to expect a corresponding `int` argument and convert it to `unsigned char` for printing.  A `char *` is not acceptable as the corresponding argument, and if one were passed, the resulting undefined behavior would more likely be along the lines of interpreting some part of the pointer value as an `unsigned char` than to output any of the pointed-to characters.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are correct.  A "If you remember the 60s - you weren't there." moment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifier in `scanf` for a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c[15];
    printf("enter a string\n");
    scanf("%14s", c);               // change %c to %s
    printf("%s\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the length limit is one less than the array size, to allow room for a `nul` terminator.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is more than 5 characters then your program will displays 5 characters perfectly and then start displaying garbage value because while printing the string it will print upto '\0' character. And if '\0' is not present at last then it will print garbage.